# create-react-app and jQuery

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I recently tried using React starter 'create-react-app' with Monster Admin Template which is on bootstrap 4. Javascript files of this template demand jQuery.
I tried importing to a index.js

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

and after all javascript files required by template through import
but I receives
[Failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c17uk.png)

Then I used it 'npm run eject' to be able to configure the webpack file and add

```
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        jQuery: 'jquery',
            $: 'jquery',
            jquery: 'jquery'
    })
```

but the template files still don't see '$' jQuery.

Did anyone have a similar problem ?

Comment: Having a similar issue. My questtion is here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51047837/loading-jquery-with-webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51047837/loading-jquery-with-webpack)