# JSPM override equivalent in Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, jspm

I have a project that contains the following block inside a jspm block in the `package.json` file.

```
"overrides": {
  "github:repoName/myPackage@master": {
    "main": "js/someFolder",
    "shim": {
      "js/someFolder": [
        "jquery"
      ]
    }
  }
```

In a separate project I want to use this same package but I will not be using JSPM. I need a way to enforce this jquery override but have been unable to successfully implement this. I am using Webpack in my project. Would this `webpack.config.js` be where I code in such an override? If possible I would like to avoid using shrinkwrap.js.

So far I have tried adding the following in my `webpack.config.js` (which admittedly is overkill):

```
plugins:[
 new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
   $: "jquery",
   "$": "jquery",
   "jQuery": "jquery",
   "jquery": "jquery",
   jQuery: "jquery",
   jquery: "jquery",
   "window.jQuery": "jquery",
   "window.$": "jquery"
 })
 .
 .
 .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered my own question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51308003/1580915

TLDR: `require` instead of `import` resolved the issue, Webpack did not need a jQuery configuration